# Patching SQLite Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I using SQLite migrations in order to update the database in a WFP client, and I'm facing the following issue:

We have a couple of versions of the software released already all of them with separate upgrade migration files:

- TimeStamp_Upgrade_1_0_1.cs
- TimeStamp_Upgrade_1_0_2.cs
- TimeStamp_Upgrade_1_0_3.cs

In version 1.0.3 we have introduced a new column/table (any change really it doesn't matter), and we would like to introduce this change into version 1.0.1 in a way that if somebody upgrades that client to 1.0.3 it doesn't break with an exception saying that this column/table already exists.

EXAMPLE:

```
public partial class Upgrade_1_0_1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TableA",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Path = c.String(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

public partial class Upgrade_1_0_3 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TableC",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Path = c.String(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

Lets say we want to add TableC to Upgrade_1_0_1 as well, how do we have to do it in a way that it doesn't break Upgrade_1_0_3?

Comment: Why would you go back and modify a prior migration? Migrations are smart enough to know what has already been applied. There are other work arounds like generating a script using `-SourceMigration` `-TargetMigration`.

Comment: yes I understand your point. The reason for this is because for every release version we consolidate the migration files for every feature into a single file, to avoid having dozens of them, so instead we have a single migration file / release. because of this if we would like to modify an existing migration file that means a future release migration file will conflict with this.

Comment: I do realise now that what we should have done instead is keeping the migration files separate, and adding in any change as a new migration file. Unfortunately we can't go back in time, so we have to deal with this somehow.